# uploading an email file using jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, applet

I am creating drag and drop file uploader using jquery. when i tried to drag an email file from ms outlook or apple mailbox and drop into that jsp file ,it's not accepting the email content.

Can anyone help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: You'll get better information if you include a jsfiddle.  Are you trying to drag the email from Outlook, or a file manager?

Comment: Am trying to drag an email from apple mailbox?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're not drag/dropping a file.  Try saving the content of the email to a `.txt` file (or Word, etc), and then uploading.

Comment: In my case i have to upload it directly to a webpage. (ie) i should have to drag an email file from apple mailbox and drop it to a webpage.i should not change the file type.